# Timing compare in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, timezone

How to compare Indian time with world's other country times in SQL Server 2008?

Means i want to know if in India its mid night 1 am what will be timing in other countries through SQL Server 2008

Comment: Can you give a context for how you will use and/or access this information? Are you interested in time-zone differences between multiple SQL servers, or simply a way to look up a time offset for a geographical location?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at `SYSUTCDATETIME()`:

```
SELECT SYSDATETIME(), SYSUTCDATETIME();
```

With UTC Time you can easily calculate the time in any other country.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server 2008 uses the [DateTimeOffset](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630289.aspx) type to represent DateTime with a timezone offset.

You can convert values from one timezone to another using the [SWITCHOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677244.aspx) function.

To create DateTimeOffset values for a specific timezone from existing date values, use [TODATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb630335.aspx).

You can get the current date and time including the offset using [SYSDATETIMEOFFSET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677334.aspx).

Finally, you can use plain-old [DATEDIFF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) to compare DateTimeOffset values and get their difference.

To get your current time in India and switch it to another timezone you have to know the proper time offset. The statement would be something like

```
DECLARE @localTime DATETIMEOFFSET=SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
SELECT @localTime, SWITCHOFFSET(@localTime,'-5:00')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @indianTime DATETIME = GETDATE()
DECLARE @timeZoneOffset SMALLINT = 3 -- or -3

SELECT DATEADD(hour, @timeZoneOffset, @indianTime)
```

See next MSDN articles: [1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724%28SQL.90%29.aspx), [2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

---

But it's better to use SQL Server 2008 and `DateTimeOffset` type which supports time zones.

So you could do next:

```
DECLARE @indianTime DATETIME = SYSDATETIMEOFFSET()
DECLARE @timeZoneOffset NVARCHAR(6) = '-03:00'

SELECT SWITCHOFFSET(@indianTime, @timeZoneOffset)
```